# How do I take 25 screenshots of my screen every second

Tags: java, screenshot

The reason I need this is cause I'm creating a free screen recorder named fraser and I really need to be able to make it have a FrameRate. Can someone please tell me how do I make it take 25 screenshots every second?

Comment: If you're going to write a real time screen recorder, Java's not exactly 'plan A'.

Comment: any efforts thus far Mr. Walrus? this kinda sounds like "HI, GIMME CODE PLZ"

Comment: [`java.awt.Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture(java.awt.Rectangle)) has a screen capture method, but I don't know if it will be efficient enough for this task.

Comment: "I am writing a free X, how do I write X?" never leads anywhere good.

Comment: You don't using native Java. With OS-dependent JINI you'd have a chance.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `java.awt.Robot`; it has a method called `createScreenCapture(Rectangle screenRect)`. For the delay between the screenshots, use for example `Thread.sleep(long millis)`.

The code for this program is up to you to write, though.

Answer (score 0):

Java introduced a screen grabber that may be of some use to you. You can change how many shots it take in time intervals. Check it out [Here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/screengrabber-178281.html)

Comment: Link-only answers are frowned upon on Stack Overflow.  It is better to include the relevant information from the link.

Answer (score 0):

See in this direction:

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(3);
```

Then you can define MyClass class:

```
class MyClass implements Runnable {
    Robot robot = new Robot();

    @Override
    public void run() {
         BufferedImage image = robot.createScreenCapture(...);
    }
}
```

And then you can do this:

```
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyClass(), 1, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```